# Redis reduce RTT with HMStore

Tags: python, redis

I have the following table structure in a redis DB, whereas all values are HMStores:

```
     Key        |        Value
-----------------------------------------------------
     test_id    |  {'name': 'name', 'column': 'abc'}
     abc        |  {'region': '1'}
```

For the first row there's the value `column` which defines the key for another row `abc` in this case. Currently I'm retrieving all values as follows:

```
 fields = redis_store.hmget('test_id', 'name', 'column')
 column = redis_store.hmget(fields[1], 'region')
```

However this results in two different connections to redis. Is there a way to use pipelining or other ways to get everything with one single query only to reduce the overhead?